# DirectX11 Shadow slope bias incorrect

Tags: c++, directx, shadows

I've recently implemented shadows on my terrain project, using PCF filtering, however, the shadows on the slopes of the terrain appear incorrect, as you can see below:

[image]

[image]

How can I remove the artifacts caused on the slopes of the terrain?  A quick search suggests implementing a slope based bias, but how would I calculate it?

Here is my pixel shader:

```
Texture2D shadowMap : register(t0);

SamplerComparisonState SampleTypeCmp : register(s0);

cbuffer SPerLightCB : register(b0)
{
    float4 ambientColour;
    float4 diffuseColour;
};

cbuffer SPerLightPosCB : register(b1)
{
    float3 lightPos;
    float padding;
};

struct PixelIn
{
    float4 Pos    : SV_POSITION;
    float4 WPos   : TEXCOORD0;
    float4 LPos   : TEXCOORD1;
    float3 Normal : NORMAL;
};

float2 texOffset(int u, int v)
{
    return float2(u * 1.0f / 1024.0f, v * 1.0f / 1024.0f);
}

float4 main(PixelIn pin) : SV_Target
{
    //re-homogenize position after interpolation
    pin.LPos.xyz /= pin.LPos.w;

    //if position is not visible to the light - dont illuminate it
    //results in hard light frustum
    if (pin.LPos.x < -1.0f || pin.LPos.x > 1.0f ||
        pin.LPos.y < -1.0f || pin.LPos.y > 1.0f ||
        pin.LPos.z < 0.0f || pin.LPos.z > 1.0f)
    {
        return ambientColour;
    }

    //transform clip space coords to texture space coords (-1:1 to 0:1) 
    pin.LPos.x = pin.LPos.x / 2 + 0.5;
    pin.LPos.y = pin.LPos.y / -2 + 0.5;
    pin.LPos.z -= 0.001f; //apply bias

    //PCF Sampling
    float sum = 0.0f;
    float x, y;

    //perform PCF filtering
    for (y = -1.5; y <= 1.5; y += 1.0)
    {
        for (x = -1.5; x <= 1.5; x += 1.0)
        {
            sum += shadowMap.SampleCmpLevelZero(SampleTypeCmp, pin.LPos.xy + texOffset(x, y), pin.LPos.z);
        }
    }

    float shadowFactor = sum / 16.0;

    //calculate ilumination
    float3 L = normalize(lightPos - pin.WPos.xyz);
    float ndotl = dot(normalize(pin.Normal), L);
    return ambientColour + shadowFactor * diffuseColour * ndotl;
}
```

Comment: There may be multiple reasons. Biasing depth won't resolve any of them. First, remove PCF filtering to see if this is the cause. If the artifacts are still present, try to increase the shadow map resolution. Your texture coordinate offsets for PCF seem a bit odd. Firstly, make sure that the offsets fit to the addressing mode (usually, texture coordinates are in the range [0, 1]). Then, don't use a loop with floating point iteration variables (it's not guaranteed that the upper bound is hit). And make sure that the offset (0, 0) is part of the sampling (which is not the case right now).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that